# Airflow webserver gettins valueError:Samesite

Tags: python, anaconda, airflow

I installed Airflow 1.10.12 using Anaconda in one of my environments.

But when I tried to follow the Quick Start Guide (at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html) I got the following error after accessing http://localhost:8080/admin/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1970, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2269, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 379, in save_session
    response.set_cookie(
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 468, in set_cookie
    dump_cookie(
  File "/home/guilherme/anaconda3/envs/engdados/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 1217, in dump_cookie
    raise ValueError("SameSite must be 'Strict', 'Lax', or 'None'.")
ValueError: SameSite must be 'Strict', 'Lax', or 'None'.
```

I tried to set the `cookie_samesite` variable at the `default_airflow.cfg` file to either None, Lax or Strict but the error persists.

**Some details of my airflow environment:**

I installed Apache airflow in my workspace using the `conda install -c anaconda airflow`
After that I create an environment on Anaconda and installed the airflow package within this environment. Then I opened the terminal and run `airflow initdb` and `airflow webserver -p 8080`. Then I went to webpage and saw the error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try with `pip install 'werkzeug<1.1.0'`

Comment: Worked, thanks. If you don't mind posting this as an answer, so I can close this question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bump `werkzeug` version to the following:

```
pip install 'werkzeug<1.0.0'
```

For Airflow >=2.0.0 change the config (airflow.cfg) `[webserver] cookie_samesite` to use `Lax` (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.1/UPDATING.md#the-default-value-for-webserver-cookie_samesite-has-been-changed-to-lax).

Comment: based on your commit here, should it be `werkzeug<1.0.0` ?
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11872

Comment: When I tried this answer I got an error `apache-airflow 2.0.1 requires werkzeug>=1.0.1,~=1.0, but you have werkzeug 0.16.1 which is incompatible`.  However I just ignored it and it still downgraded successfully and fixed the airflow problem.

Comment: @Selah keep the `werkzeug` value that Airflow 2.0.1 requires but change the config to use `Lax` (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#the-default-value-for-webserver-cookie_samesite-has-been-changed-to-lax)